# assign headers based on existing row that is not the same row and column / dataframe in R

Tags: r

Question. How to extract the row number that will be the header?
I think I can assign that row as a header by using index number.

header is c(a,b,c)

data
6*4 matrix

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 #header
d a b c #headera,b,c
d 1 1 1
d 1 1 1
a b c e #headera,b,c
2 2 2 e
2 2 2 e
```

output
4*3 matrix

```
a b c #header
1 1 1
1 1 1
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

my code..

```
str_which(df, 'a') #idetify row number
```

Comment: HOw do you end up with that output? What happens to b c e??

Comment: sorry, I edit input data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've written above, you need to filter rows that contain 'a', 'b', 'c' letters consequentially, which implies that the sequence might start either from `v1` or `v2`. Henceforth, I believe this will solve your issue:

```r
# create an indexed data frame
df.with.index <- mutate(df, IDX = 1:n())

# filter the data frame by the condition above, and output the index
dplyr::filter(df.with.index,
              (v2 == 'a' & v3 == 'b' & v4 == 'c')
              | (v1 == 'a' & v2 == 'b' & v3 == 'c'))$IDX
```

This will result in:

```r
[1] 1 4
```

If you need to test the rows over whether they contain only letter 'a', you might want to use this:

```r
dplyr::filter(df.with.index, (v1 == 'a' | v2 == 'a' | v3 == 'a' | v4 == 'a'))$IDX
```